# New Python Gmail API - Only Retrieve Messages from Yesterday

Tags: python, gmail-api

I've been updating some scripts to the new Python Gmail API. However, I am confused as how to update the following so that I only retrieve messages from yesterday. Can anyone show me how to do this?

The only way I can currently see is to loop through all messages and only parse those with epochs in the correct time range. However, that seems horribly inefficient if I have 1000's of messages. There must be a more efficient way to do this.

```
from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
import os
import httplib2
import email
from apiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest
import base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import datetime

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = '/Users/sokser/Downloads/client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'gmail-python-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title']:
        return False
    elif re.match('<!--.*-->', str(element)):
        return False
    return True

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.

    Creates a Gmail API service object and outputs a list of label names
    of the user's Gmail account.
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
    #Get yesterdays date and the epoch time
    yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)
    unix_time= int(yesterday.strftime("%s"))

    messages = []

    message = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
    for m in message['messages']:
        #service.users().messages().get(userId='me',id=m['id'],format='full')
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me',id=m['id'],format='raw').execute()
        epoch = int(message['internalDate'])/1000

        msg_str = str(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII')),'utf-8')
        mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)
        #print(message['payload']['parts'][0]['parts'])
        #print()
        mytext = None
        for part in mime_msg.walk():
            mime_msg.get_payload()
            #print(part)
            #print()
            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                soup = BeautifulSoup(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
                visible_texts = filter(visible,texts)
                mytext = ". ".join(visible_texts)
            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html' and not mytext:
                mytext = part.get_payload(decode=True)
        print(mytext)
        print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass queries to the `messages.list` method that searches for messages within a date range. You can actually use any [query supported by Gmail's advanced search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).

You do this, which will just return messages.

```
message = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
```

But can do this to search for messages sent yesterday, by passing the `q` keyword argument, and a query specifying the `before:` and `after:` keywords.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(1)

# do your setup...

user_id = 'user email address'

# Dates have to formatted in YYYY/MM/DD format for gmail
query = "before: {0} after: {1}".format(today.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'),
                                        yesterday.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))

response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id,
                                           q=query).execute()
# Process the response for messages...
```

You can also try this against their [GMail `messages.list` reference page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list).